# MPI4py profiling with VTune

Tags: python, profiling, intel, mpi4py, intel-vtune

I have an MPI python application and I try to profile it using VTune. Since I am running my application on a HPC, I am obliged to use a terminal. I tried several times and I am getting the following error:

amplxe: Error: Failed to attach to the specified target process. Please make sure the process exists and VTune Amplifier process has enough permissions to attach to the target process. See the Troubleshooting help topic for more details.

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this issue and I have failed to find some instruction on how to use amplxe-cl or amplxe-python.

Comment: On Linux, you might need `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0` in your sysctl settings to allow debugging / tracing of non-child processes.  (`ptrace` is the Linux system call used by stuff like `gdb`.  You'd need this to let gdb attach to a process, instead of debugging a process started from within gdb.)  You might also need `kernel.perf_event_paranoid = 0`.  Put these in `/etc/sysctl.d/99-local.conf`

Comment: Thank you, but I believe that your answer requires admin access to the system. I do not have admin privileges in the system I am using. On the other hand, vtune is already installed and I may be able to ask the admins to make such changes

Comment: Can you please provide amplxe-cl command you're using?

Comment: This is the command: `ibrun amplxe-cl -collect hotspots -r results mpi4py_test.py`. If I do `ibrun mpi4py_test.py` I get the correct results.